# Can we have a clear place for the help section in the new layout?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design, navigation

The new layout has been rolled out everywhere.

[image: top bar at Stack Overflow]

The help section is in the footer

[image: "help" in the footer section]

<strike>It took me a while to figure out it wasn't at the top (and I've been here a while).</strike>

You have to click on the sites bar on the right and it's not clear where to find it by looking at the icons.

[image: location of help link in new top bar]

Unlike the current layout for all other sites

[image: old top bar]

which is much clearer on where to find things, with a drop down menu

[image: help dropdown on old top bar]

Can we have the help section in a prominent place, as we are so often referring new users to it?

Comment: It's in the hamburger, right next to the pickles: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345218/visually-distinguish-help-from-chat-in-multi-collider

Comment: @JoshCaswell that's the old scheme, or maybe not :/

Comment: No, they added it to the new one recently: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASluy.png (Sorry, pasted the wrong image link initially.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell well that's not helpful (the link not your comment), it took me  a meta question to find it.hm

Comment: @JoshCaswell cheers, that was helpful, unlike the new layout *all puns intended*

Comment: Questions about the new topbar are not on-topic here are the moment and should be asked on MSO instead.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I assumed it was going to affect all sites. Shouldn't all the sites have a say? hm *the plot thickens*

Comment: *Maybe* it will be rolled out to the entire network, but not now. Just like Documentation and the new navigation.

Comment: @PatrickHofman *sob* I can't keep up with meta *sigh* I need *help* :D

Comment: This should probably be updated to the new "everywhere else" top bar? ;p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed on January 5th 2018; the help menu is available for all users regardless of reputation or privilege.